# Снятие pyarmor с python кода

Tags: python, python-3.x

мне нужна помощь со снятием pyarmor с кода. Однажды я наложил его на свой код, а в будущем мне потребовалось изменить его, но к сожалению я не нашёл исходники. Большая просьба, кто может помочь снять pyarmor? Или это невозможно?
Буду благодарен любой помощи с вашей стороны

Вот сам код:

```
from pytransform import pyarmor_runtime
pyarmor_runtime()
__pyarmor__(__name__, __file__, b'PYARMOR\x00\x00\x03\t\x00a\r\r\n\x08-\xa0\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00@\x00\x00\x00\xea\n\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x18\xf8\x92O\xa5\x82\xd3aT\xab/6\x12\x8bH\xe6\xe2\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xfb\xd5OU\xf8\x89\x1be\x07:/[[o\xc5k\xff\xe2\x19D\xba\xbd\xfc\xd4\xdc>\x18\xe4\x9de\xb129\xb3\xfb\xfa\xa5\x98w<\x82\xfa\x02\x81\xf26\x1d1\x1f^\xe7\xb7\xd5\xa4\x8d\x1bow\xb6\xc3/\xbb\x97\xa0^\xfc\x97\xf8\xe13[\x80g\xbf\x15\xea<.\xb2\xc4\xf7\xc0\x1f6\xd2G\xde\x99-X^|\xe1\xf8\xa2p{\x13\x8eCSa\x83\x92\xbdeSx\xc6\xec\x95\xd0\xa1\xc6\xf9\xe5@\x161I\x02\x19/S\xbd\xff\x96!\xbc\x01\xe2\xc2\r7\xe1\x0b\xe2\x8e\x8c\xf6\x0c\x9e\xaf\x08h\xa6DW\x04\xbfo\x9fY\x1dT{\x82\xb7\xca)I;?\xa8q\xc9\xa1o\xe0\x10y\x86V\xf5\x9aD%9\xa8\x11\x00d\xddK\xcd3\x9f\x84\x94\xd9D:< \x89I4\x18\x19(\x06\xe0Q02?\x88J\x90\xe3.o\xfb\x1d\xf4Q\xf3\xf01z\x9a\x9bj\x82%A\xde\xb6j\xc3\ro\xa2\xf5\x82\xa6d\xcf\x08\xed\xfbS\xd9\x9eE\xa6\x9e\x8b@}\x97\xd6\xcd\x159`E\xb4\xb1\x14\x99\xcf\xa3\xa6\xde\xe8%\x85f\x08\xee\x80\x1a\x0f\x1bcD\x9d`p\xca\xeb\xd6kU\x91\x9d\x1fZO\xf0\xbc\xe8\xdbW\x8e\xca\xfe\x19\x81g\x19\x13\xe0\x7f\x1a\xc5\x86\xd6~\x98B\xb5\x84\x91\x00\x0b\xf5\xc8\xea\x12G\x97\xf8\xc8\xe1\xc9\xad\xea\xe0\xe8\xa5u\xdd\xe6\x90\xd6?X|\xa6\xef\xb3 Rq\x16gr\xb1\xe7\x926Hz\xeb\xb2w/\xd0_\xfe\xd19\x97\xd1\r\xee\xa5\xf2\xdf}\x89C\xd7|\x0f\x81\xdf\xe9\xdb@\x8e=I\x1c\x1bp\xabk^\x9b\xbc\x80\x8c^d\x15\xa3\x10\x7f\xbct\nV\r\xf8\xe2\xeb\x139&\xe2\x9ddI\x80\xab\xe3\xd9"\xefs5TH\xe0[1\xf1V{^B\xbc\x16z\x92\x9c<\xc8\xd6\xab\x83\x9c=\t\xf7\x9c\t\x90\x0b3?\x91\xe4\x00 \x91o\x97cg\xab\'\x11\xfc\xedg\xc1u\xa5V\xda3a\x82\x9c%+Hi\x96\xec\x15\xf8\xd9\x8b\r\xedd\x81\xa5o\xb2{\xff\xa1)\xee\xaf\xc7\xf3\xa7\x9d\xe3\xee\x03\xf4\x83(\x17\xd9\xc48\xa4\x1cNa\xf9gjS\xa0\x9c\xbe\xc3qq\xb9\x01\x1c\x17\x05Sw\x9e\x86F\xee\x97\xafs\xa3\xb2\x02Xp\xcc\xfe\xa9\x1f\xa6\'\x1dnB\xa2qlN\xf6B\x10\x14\xd5r\xea\xd3L\xd3h\xcb.\xb4\xf7)\\A\xb2\x87\xb5<!]L\xb7F\x98\xcas\xea#\x03i\x08s%h(\x883i\xe3\xbb>\x03\xd5\x07\xeb\xc1L\xe3\x8c\x85\x1du\x1d$\x1d/\xe9\x80\xe8\xdeC\xce\x0eN\x1b\x1f\xd3ZG\xd9\xe2\xd54\xac\x06\xf9\xadL-\xe0\x817S\xe4\x13S\xf7 \xde\xe9\x106\n\xbak\x85:A\xf2\xb9B\x96\x06\xcagQ\x1fm90jQ\x12SD\xc0j\x80\xa9q\x86}e\x0e\xe6+\xe3\xfb\xeeEd59X\x10\x93\t\x89\xee2\xd2T\xd3F\xa9\x8f\'\x8a\xeb\x93;*S\x8a\xa3\xa2\x18lhM)\x87V\xb7l\x0f\x9b\xa4\xa8\xa3[\xd46)\xe1U\xb9\xfeK?\x05\xde\xf8\x04\x9c\x08\xe8c%\x0e\xae\xe2U%[\xee\'\x17#\xfc\xb5\xc97\xbe\x9fk\xd9f\xad\xde^\xe6\x8at\xdb7\x8f\xb4\xbbf\xce\x8cw&}\x12\x00\xe4S\xfd\x14\xff\xbf\xbe\xfd`\xca\xbb\xb00\xc6\x1e\x9c:\xc4\xa70\xcd\xd9#\x1c\xd4(O\xb3\x00\xb3\xdc\xaa%E\x08\x12\xcer\xea\xdf\x072ZP4\xe1\x95q\xf4\x031.\x89\xb7{.\xd8;\x19b\xe8\xe7Z&\xc0\x80P}\xaa\xb5\x90\x0c\x82I\xa3\xc4\xf1(4~`Os5\xe9J\xd3\x06A\x14\x03\xe9\xee<\xa6\x88S\xf7IZ\x07dv\x11~\xdc\xa3`o..\xbf\xa2\x85S\xbf\xb7\xe4\xbdv\x0b\xd8\x06\x8dr\xc2K\x81\x83\x05o\x91>dig\x7f\xc2O\xf5^\x9a\x0b\xa4-\xfc\xa4\x8aQ\x15\x03%\xc9\x90\xe0Q\xe2\xf6\xf0\x8b\x15?\xceg\xc24W\xdc\xda\xb1\xd7x\xdf\xc0\x95\x8d*\xd6\x04(\xe0\n\xeb\x96\xf7\xec\x13-JJ\x15!2\x16\xfe\x99\xd9\xc7\xcdy6\xceVb\x8c\xcd\xebO\x8c\xed\xc8\xabO\x1e\x0bn\xf3\x00@G\xf7\xb6&Y\xb6\xc5J\xb4\xb7\x05\x15]"\xf6P\xfddy\x11\xb0\xb1\x14(Q\x04\x94\xd7\xbeq3\xae\x9c\xcc\xab^*T\x00\x19\x9b\xf1\n\xf8\xc3\x1aR\xbe\x0f\xf6\xa5\xd0\xc3H\xedw\xdc\x94\xe7NO\xaf\xe2\x19\xafG-\xabx\xec<C-\x17-\x8a\x8e\xc4\x14m-\xe6/\r&\x91\x90\xe6\x89T>WO\x0b\x7f\xec\xf8K\xb6\x12I>\xbb\xcd\xe1\xb4\xb3%\xe7\x0c\x0e\x93\xd1\xa7\x1fVZ~\xfa\xd0\x12\x0c\x8b>t\xeeQ\xf33N/^\xec\xde\xbb\x9c\xe6]\x1f\n\x89\xf7b\xc3\x9b2\x8bw\x9f`\x93!\xee\x9d#M\xffLY\xcb\x17\x0f\x86\xf9k\xfd\xd3u\xd7\x0c\xc5\xcf<\xc3\xcf6\xac\xd0\x86\xb9}\x8c\x15\xe1a\x0cY\xdf\xd6t\x7f\xa1\xa7\x83\x98hwz\x12\x92\xd6\x90W\xf2\x1cG9@\xafqiR\x92\x80U\xd3e\xfd\x13\xda\xa3z\xcd03\xa4\xc1\xce\xb3T\x8f\x8b\x06F\xcf2\x07\x10\n\x19W/\xad\xc2\xe4@J\xe8\xf7\xba\x8bW\xc8\x18\xcdK\x10\xe0o@\x15\t\x1b\x0fF=\x9byn\x88\xae\xbccs\x17\r\x0c\xfc\xfaoM\xa9\x8c\x83=\xb9&}\xdd(\x97\xe4\x9e\x1e\x9b.\xd0\xc9Fh\x17_\xec\xaf\xeaP/\\Mfb\x11\xd99\xb4\xc7p\xd5\x81\xbb\x12\xdf,\x06\xf2:\x8d\xdad\x16[\xf0\t\xa7 \xf2\x95\xbb\x17\xea\x90\xc8\x9b\x89t@\xf6\xaf\xa5\x98\xe9,3\xc8\xdb}\xa7~=\xf3\xb0\xc4\xfe\xd3\xc6\xf8\xcev\xfc\xbe\xef\x87%"\x87/\xae\x0e\xcd\xf4L\x98\x1d\xce\xfa\xda\x14{\xa7\x00\xb6s\xcf|\xb8\x04\x8d\\\x9b\xeb$\x16Q\x1cb\xc0\xeb\\\xf2\xc2\x1a\x1f\xed\x1d\xec\x13\xfa\x87\x15$\xacR%\xba.\xeav\xe1e\x0el\xe7\x90\xf3\x99&\xd1\xa2\xfd\x86\x81LJ\xf6\x05:x\xba\xbb\xabN\xc6\t\x1e\x9a\x8d7\x1blRsn@\xb8<eB\xdb:taZ\x88\x83>\xdd\xaeL*\x80\x93Ol\xe2\x11\xc6\xe7\x98L\xb5\xc75 \xde\x8f\xa7\x9e"pP\xff\xd8Fg*\xc5J#\xea$\xb6\xb5\xf0\x84\xbdv\xc3M}~%\xdc\xdd5\x9f\xcc^\xb8\xb2T\xe4,\xa5\t\xe23 \xa6_\x95\x9c\xff\xed\xa4\xb0\x1fL\xc1\xeb1$-\xb9\xf9r\xf4H\xcd\x9b\xb11\x06%\x06\xb6\xa3\xbc\xb7\xb0v(1\xf8Xd\xc9\x10)\xcf7D\x19\x01\xd3\x80E\xc4c\xc5\xa8"]\x1f\xa3\xf8\x0bI\x83\x07t\xc8.\xa5?\xe7\xbf\xe64\xf6\x1eO\x0c\xe5\xbc\xcfm\x9d\\+,\x87\x08\xc5\x9f3\xb8\xf6ps\xfa%l\x1b<\xde\x93\xd8\xe4h\x17F\xd0E\xa4\xc7m\xde-]\x93\x8a\xaa\x9f\xf5t]\xa30v\x9d$X\x13\x81rtI\xb4\xfc\x86Tq\xa3L\x7f\xbd\xc4\xbf\x85\xec\xe21\xa3\xda\x1az>\xbb\xd6pw\xc5#\xb6g\x94\xb3\x1aq;g\xa0\x01_\x99\x82V\x8e\xb0\xbcG\x18\x8fo\x07\xbc0\xf2$\xfd\xder\x06\xa8\x80\xbc\xa3\\(J\xc5Fk\x11\xe8\xecJ\xca\x93\xb6p\xc6\x81y\x14\r\xe6\xccB\\y~\x0c\x058\xa8\xc3R/`\xac\xcdV\x1c\x08+M\x1e\xa0\xc2\xcb04\xf3\xc5^\xfb6\xe1\x9d\x8e\'\xea]\xfd\xc4\x8f\xb3\xe2\xe3\x11yU\'\xa2\xc53\x86\x96\xe5a\x97"\xea\xac\x91\xf9l\x06\xf7\'tA&O\x07\x04\nP\x10\xc7N)\xa7\xbc\x03\x92\xf8h9\x9c\xc8\xefY\xe6)\xe1\xbd\xc5\xb23\xb81A\xa2\xd1\x01\xd3\xaf\xd6*\xb7:\xaboy\xab1\xc5\x08H\xba\x88f\x90B\xa0\x8e1e\x15>\x91\x17\x03\x97Z\x94\x0f0\x81\x08\xd8\xce\x01\xe3Bg\xe8\xe2\x9aa q\xd5\xc3\x17\xc91(\xef\xb6n5\xc6|\x0f@u,pL\xcfM\xf2\xd0\x12\xc7\x05\xa2\xe4LH\xee\x87dA\xc2\xa1S\x1e\xbb\xc8\xe4\xebA4:\x98{\xffOT\x02\xf6\x9b\xf8\xe43\xc3\x97\xd2`\x92\x8e\xd9 G\xd6E\xad\xb4x\x1d\xa4}K\xe8\xcb\x17_\x89\xaa\x8a\xcc\x8c\xcbF\x85\x00\x02\x93\xa7+\xce\xc7\x04\xb6\xfc\xc3\xf3u\xf9\xac\x93f\x9f\x11\x94\xec\xa1\xc8\x94\x106\x9d\xa4\x01\x13\xa8T\x8d\xbe\xc2\xea\xdeD\x06j\xd9\x85\x1c\x17\x8e\xb43&^\x93\xe96\x05v\xce\xe1\x88\x87\x0b!;MJ"\x9a\x86\x0b\x93\xdb\x1cD\x1d0X\xb9\xca04\xd7\x14\xfa\x7f\xd0=p\xf2w\x89\x83.\xb4^\x8avR\xa0\x01\x9e>"`\x8e\x13=\x11\xb0\xdaP\x0f\xa8{\xee\t?\xd1\xf2\x1f\xb5MKO\x86 \xce\xd1M\xbc;@\xeb\xeccgld*\xfa\xc8\x80L\\\xa9\xd9\x8d0{H\xf1\xfdQ(1\x8a\x94\x97\x16\x01\xb0\xdeg\xb5x\x04 Qw\x10\xf9\x0b\x99\xf1\'^]\xa7\x91\xf2KnF#Oo\x00E\xb70$$\x9d\xba\x92\xbe\xe7\x17\xb2#\xedP\xe7\x88\x13\x9f\\Rf\xa2\x89\xf9\x00\xdeT\xa3{\xae\x17\xca;aLR\x90\x15\xcat\x07\xaf\xc22\xfdS\x92o@\xefB\x9d=\xd113\n\xae5\\\xe7\xb1\x1c\x0b\x1e)\x06\x17\x99\x12;pf\xe3z~\x8e\x9e^\x1f\xaa#\xf8YU\xdd\x08\x84\xa7\xf0\xaa/\xb4\x1aL\xf0\x1f\xb1\xd5L\xfa\xf6\xc9\x88]7s\x8c*\xf7b\xe0Af:\xbb\xa3\xd1\x9e\xbd\xe4CP2\xff\x9e\x97\x1fO\x00\x98\xf8\xcc@C\x0e\xc3\xcbm\xe6\x97\x9f\x16\xf1\xec\xc7Q\xd7Z\xc9\xab~\xa6\xac\x08+j\xfd\xcbl\x88\xae\xafN<\x93\xd4\xc8s\xd2\x19\xb3\x91C\xc7\x0e*\x18X\x92a\xe2\x11\xa0l\xb1\x8a\x84\x10\xe0\x93Er4t\xeeD\xa5\xb5\x12"\x89\x8a\x02f\xden]\xf1Z7\x05u\xf8\x08\xea\x1b\xc4|x\xa35\\\xb7\x89\x011\xc6\xe5\xedl\x0c\xb1I\xc8\x14\x8ag\xdem2I\xe8\xcb\xa0\x81\xbf\xd2C}\xa33\xb2\x17H\xc5\x19\x05/\xd4\x9b\xdd-\x12\x0b\xce !X \x91dT\x02\x8em\x81JK\xd5\x8bq\x1f"\x82\xa3\xde\xd7:\x87\xa8\x03\xf9\x07\x99\x08\xbc\x82\xb0\x85^\xc3\x10\xa7\xe9i]\xc2\xbcn\xc2\xd7g\xdd\x8c:\x01\xa6\xb6\xe1\xebN\x8e\xf7m\xce\xfa\xd6\x130\xea\x00\\V\xaaU\xe4ei\xc7\x84A7\x07\x06\xb2\x9f\xe1\xf8Q\xa9&\x8c\x1bB&p\xd1\x97l\xf6\x19\x0cp\xf9Z\r\xae\xd6\xb0\xd8\xf8\x91\xfb<\x9c\x8ar `\x0c\xf3\\\x00\xa1\x94\x18\xa7\xde\x9c\xbaa\xff\x19]O]\xff\xbc\x12\x1b\x82=\x84\xedB\x02g\xe2\x17\x86\xc0")\xb3\x0e$\xa4oX\x02\xbf\xde\xb1\x1e\x08\xc6\x91\xc6uSE\x85\xa1\xeb};\xa4\x06mR_\x86"+l\x8217\x13\xf0\x15\x88J\x9a)\xe0k\x17\x0b\x90\xed\x83\x91\xad\'o+pl\xa7H\x96+\xa7\xc0\xa5\xd3\xab6\x1f\xe3X/\xeb;\xf2\xa4\x96\xbb\x10\xd8\xcd\x08\x12=\x01\xc5\x9ca\xb7\x98\x9a{\xb9\xf0\x95\xc0\xe3h\xd3m:w\xfdj\x99\x98@\xdf\x99\xb4\xd9|.\xf0\x7f[\xea\xec\xb7e\x89P\x80\x85\x0f\x10o\x1co\xf4\xdb\xf2\xdc\xac\xb7\x99\xfd\xcc4\xfb\xd3U\x95\xbe\x7f0>Z\x7f\x8eM\xdc\x8ak\x19\xa4\xb4\x86\x11\xbd\x86l\xf6\x18L- \t\xc2\xe0\xc7A\xfcZy\xd1\xa2\xd0l\x02\xacV\xaa\xe20+j\xf0\x19\xc1\x88\xa9\xfd\xec\x00\xdc\xf2zh\x83n^\xe4\xe3\x9a\xda\xc0', 2)
```

Comment: посмотрите в эту [сторону](https://github.com/Kechinator/unpyarmor)

Comment: с помощью inspect ты можешь получить любой объект в рантайме и принтануть его код.

Comment: @ДимаВиноградов у меня происходит ошибка ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'unpyarmor'
(я устанавливал через python setup.py install, а потом pip install unpyarmor, но это не помогает(. Сможете сделать пожалуйста расшифровку за меня?)